# Vendor directory not being generated during ember-cli project build

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to build/run an ember-cli based project that I got from a colleague.  When I try and run it with

```
> ember server
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
    > ember server
    version: 0.0.40
    ENOENT, no such file or directory "vendor/"
    Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory "vendor/"
      at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:654:18)
      at walkSync (/Users/ember/projects/ember/modal-example/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/walk-sync/index.js:14:20)
      at /Users/ember/projects/ember/modal-example/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-merge-trees/index.js:26:26
      at tryCatch (/Users/ember/projects/ember/modal-example/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/commonjs/rsvp/-internal.js:163:16)
      at invokeCallback (/Users/ember/projects/ember/modal-example/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/commonjs/rsvp/-internal.js:172:17)
      at publish (/Users/ember/projects/ember/modal-example/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/commonjs/rsvp/-internal.js:150:13)
      at flush (/Users/ember/projects/ember/modal-example/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/commonjs/rsvp/asap.js:51:9)
      at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Before starting the server - I successfully ran both 'npm install' and 'bower install'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: no such file or directory "vendor/"

Answer (score 1):

do you have a `.bowerrc` file in the project? the content should be:

```
{
  "directory": "vendor"
}
```

Then run `bower install` again

Comment: since ember-cli 0.46 bower directory is now call ```bower_components```

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly adding a .bowerrc file works - but it turns out what I really needed to do was run ...

```
> ember init
```

Once I ran that the .bowerrc file was created for me.