# Trying to install truffle on Windows 10 by "$npm install - g truffle" Got a bunch of problems

Tags: npm, truffle

$ npm install -g truffle
npm WARN deprecated to-iso-string@0.0.2: to-iso-string has been deprecated, use                                                                                                                                   @segment/to-iso-string instead.
npm WARN deprecated jade@0.26.3: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install th                                                                                                                                  e latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher                                                                                                                                   to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

> scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall C:\Users\Zachary Zhong\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module                                                                                                                                  s.staging\scrypt-b6fa2906
>   node node-scrypt-preinstall.js

C:\Users\Zachary Zhong\AppData\Roaming\npm\truffle -> C:\Users\Zachary Zhong\App                                                                                                                                  Data\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\cli.js
C:\Users\Zachary Zhong\AppData\Roaming\npm\truffle-exec -> C:\Users\Zachary Zhon                                                                                                                                  g\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\exec.js

> scrypt@6.0.3 install C:\Users\Zachary Zhong\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\t                                                                                                                                  ruffle\node_modules\scrypt
>   node-gyp rebuild

C:\Users\Zachary Zhong\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\scr                                                                                                                                  ypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modul                                                                                                                                  es\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )                                                                                                                                    else (node "" rebuild )
Warning: Missing input files:
C:\Users\Zachary Zhong\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\scr                                                                                                                                  ypt\build..\scrypt\win\include\config.h
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,                                                                                                                                   please add the "/m" switch.
  Copying scrypt/win/include/config.h to scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0/config.h
  The system cannot find the file specified.
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the                                                                                                                                   file specified. [C:\Users\Zachary Zhong\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle                                                                                                                                  \node_modules\scrypt\build\copied_files.vcxproj]

TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the                                                                                                                                   file specified. [C:\Users\Zachary Zhong\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle                                                                                                                                  \node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt_wrapper.vcxproj]

gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` fail                                                                                                                                  ed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\                                                                                                                                  npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces                                                                                                                                  s.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodej                                                                                                                                  s\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Zachary Zhong\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\nod                                                                                                                                  e_modules\scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
C:\Users\Zachary Zhong\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\truffle\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "truffle"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the scrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs scrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls scrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Zachary Zhong\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1

Comment: Please format your question correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

I've got 2 guides for installing on Windows:

- Installing on Windows 10 using Ubuntu bash (preferred)
  https://davidburela.wordpress.com/2017/05/12/how-to-install-truffle-testrpc-on-ubuntu-or-windows-10-with-windows-subsystem-for-linux/
- Installing on Windows
  https://davidburela.wordpress.com/2016/11/18/how-to-install-truffle-testrpc-on-windows-for-blockchain-development/

Comment: Any chance you've had a chance to update this with ganache-cli?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have not include any details about your dev environment, see this StackOverflow thread that discusses the same problem as yours: [node gyp error TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33183161/1373554)