# Facing error while installing oracledb package using npm

Tags: node.js, npm, node-oracledb

I have followed all the steps mentioned over https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb for setting up an environment to develop an app who connects with oracle. I'm trying to install node-oracledb for same but when i'm issuing following command it throws an error:

```
D:\Parth\userprofiles>npm install oracledb --save

> oracledb@1.13.1 install D:\Parth\userprofiles\node_modules\oracledb
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\Parth\userprofiles\node_modules\oracledb>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (
node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modu
les\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the
 file specified. [D:\Parth\userprofiles\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vc
xproj]


gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` fail
ed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
s.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Parth\userprofiles\node_modules\oracledb
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN userprofiles@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "oracledb" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! oracledb@1.13.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the oracledb@1.13.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the oracledb package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs oracledb
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls oracledb
```

Comment: do you have c++ installed on your system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node gyp error TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183161/node-gyp-error-tracker-error-trk0005-failed-to-locate-cl-exe-the-system-c)

Comment: I have separately installed Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable @Arpit

Comment: {npm config set msvs_version 2013 --global} solved the issue for me. Thanks for looking into this.